# Mockery of a scholar

Tags: sharia, sin, tawba, islamic-scholar

Assalamu Alaykum brothers, I want to ask you a question. If a person mocks a scholar on an Islamic matter (when alone) then sincerely repents should he apologize to that scholar too? Thanks if you respond